# how to test redis and apache ignite in sever

Tags: docker, redis, server, performance-testing, apacheignite

I am testing redis and apache ignite in displaying structured data using data stored in the mongodb database, previously I have done this test locally by creating a docker container of mongodb, redis, and apache ignite, then sending data in the mongo database to redis and ignite using python code.

and after the data was sent I created an API to display the data and I tested the api in the jmeter application, but my mentor told me to do this test on the server to get a better comparison value.

for that how to do this test by uploading mongo, redis and ignite to the server ???